# Discord Node Js delete json require in folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord

So, I'm building a discord bot using node js, and one of my functions uses JSON files which stores information about a given thing, and I want to write a command (in discord) where if I call it with a name associated with a particular JSON, it will reload the JSON, and add it back to `Discord.Collections` I have in `index.js`.

Here is my function initially adding the JSON files into the cache in `index.js`:

```js
...
const categories = ["Characters", "Groups", "Items", "Locations", "Concepts"]
const subjectMap = new Discord.Collection();

for (const categ of categories) {
  console.log("Loading: " + categ);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------");
  const jsonFiles = fs.readdirSync('./WikiJsons/' + categ + '/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.json'));

  for (const file of jsonFiles) {
    const subjName = file.substring(0, file.length - 5).toLowerCase()
    console.log("Loaded Wiki for: " + subjName);
    try {
      const subjContent = require('./WikiJsons/' + categ + '/' + file);
      subjectMap.set(subjName, subjContent);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
...
```

Here is the full code for `update.js`, where I want to delete the require() on a particular JSON file.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'update',
  description: 'Reloads json Content for given subject',
  args: true,
  aliases: ['upw', 'updat'],
  execute(message, args, dev, subjectMap) {
    const subjectName = args[0].toLowerCase();
    const subject = subjectMap.get(subjectName) || subjectMap.find(sbj => sbj.aliases && sbj.aliases.includes(subjectName));

    if (!subject) return message.channel.send(`There is no subject with name or alias \`${subjectName}\`, ${message.author}!`);


    delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../WikiJsons/${subject.type}/${subject.name}.json`)];

    try {
      const newSubject = require(`./${subject.name}.json`);
      subjectMap.set(newSubject.name, newSubject);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      message.channel.send(`There was an error while reloading \`${subject.name}\`:\n\`${error.message}\``);
    }
    message.channel.send(`Subject \`${subject.name}\` reload complete.`);


  },
};
```

When I try and run it, `index.js` seems to run fine, but when I try and run the command associated with update, passing an argument of `quinn`. (It does exist in the `subjectMap` before I run this, I've tested that) I get the following:

```js
Error: Cannot find module './quinn.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Bob\Documents\GitHub\DndBot\Node-Js-Discord-Bot\commands\update.js
- C:\Users\Bob\Documents\GitHub\DndBot\Node-Js-Discord-Bot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Bob\Documents\GitHub\DndBot\Node-Js-Discord-Bot\commands\update.js:17:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bob\Documents\GitHub\DndBot\Node-Js-Discord-Bot\index.js:108:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

I've tested, and this is the line (from update.js) causing the error:

```js
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../WikiJsons/${subject.type}/${subject.name}.json`)];
```

As for my file structure, I have
Node-Js-Discord-Bot as my root folder for the project, and the other files structured like:

```
Node-Js-Discord-Bot:
    index.js
    WikiJsons
        Characters
    commands
        update.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the line you tested is the wrong one ?

I feel like that the first require inside of the `try` statement is pointing to the wrong directory.

From what I understood, I suppose it should be `../WikiJsons/${subject.type}/${subject.name}.json`.

Comment: Thank you! It was a silly error with me pointing out the wrong directory as you mentioned. I was too narrow sighted by the other factors.